# can't pass argument to QThread

Tags: python, pyside6

I want to pass arguments to a QThread when it's called but for some reason I always get this error:
`QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running`

Here's my code:

```py
from PySide6.QtCore import QObject, Qt, QThread, Signal

class sendEmailObject(QObject):
    finished = Signal()
    def begin(self, arg):
        dostuff()
        self.finished.emit()

def applic():
    thread = QThread()
    object = sendEmailObject()
    object.moveToThread(thread)
    object.finished.connect(thread.quit)
    thread.started.connect(lambda func: object.begin("argument"))
    thread.start()

applic()
```

Edit: This is obviously not my complete code (because it is around 1000 lines). It's just something I wrote to explain my problem. The "applic" function is defined inside a QMainWindow on my original code. The thread class "sendEmailObject" is defined outside of QMainWindow

Comment: Your `QThread` instance will be destroyed as soon as `applic` finishes.  The error message you see is coming from its destructor.

Comment: I didn't make clear what my problem was. When that error message pops up, the whole script stops (the whole QMainWindow) which is something that I don't want to happen. 

Now about the QThread being destroyed, shouldn't the QThread get destroyed once the dostuff() finishes or does Qt handle that automatically?

Comment: Sorry. but I can only try to diagnose the problem based on the code shown.  If my comment does not help then you need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: You're completely right but I don't have the ability right now to post any other script as I'm not on my main computer. Could you explain the second part of my comment? 
("Now about the QThread being destroyed, shouldn't the QThread get destroyed once the dostuff() finishes or does Qt handle that automatically?")

Comment: Under normal circumstances the new thread managed by `QThread` would end once `dostuff` completes.  But if the `QThread` destructor is invoked it won't wait for `dostuff` to complete -- you need to manage the lifetime of the `QThread` yourself.

Comment: @Jimminer without a valid MRE it's almost impossible to provide adequate answers. That said: 1. as already pointed out, both `thread` and `object` have no persistent reference, they will be destroyed as soon as `applic` returns (which means, immediately); 2. Qt signals execute connected functions based on the [thread affinity](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html#qobject-and-threads) of the object that receives the signal, lambdas don't provide this aspect so the function won't be correctly run in the thread; 3. `object` is a python builtin, you should not use that name for a variable.

Comment: @musicamante I don't mind the thread getting destroyed as long as it runs what's under `begin`. With some minor testing, I found out that the error about the QThread getting destroyed is present even when the line with `thread.started.connect` is removed. Simply starting the Thread "crashes" (at least from what I can tell) my application. As per the lambda, I don't mind removing it and implementing it into a seperate function if I get the Thread to properly start. Thanks.

Comment: @Jimminer yes, not only you should mind about it getting destroyed, but you should really understand and be aware of its lifespan. It's not a normal object that gets destroyed when it returns, it is executed *in another thread*: it's almost like closing a terminal opened by a program, while it's still executing some command: the program is your main thread (which launches `applic`), the terminal is the new thread, and the command is `begin`: you close the terminal, you kill the command. If the thread has no reference, it will be destroyed immediately **along with** the function its processing.

Comment: @musicamante okay I got what you mean. I wasn't aware that the existence of a thread is so important to the other threads. Thanks so much for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by passing `self` in QThread() and removing `func` from the lambda.

In this case, `self` is not defined but when running this code inside a QMainWindow, there are no errors.

I don't know why passing `self` in the QThread fixed the problem so if anyone knows the reason, it would be nice to leave a comment explaining it so I can later add it to the answer.

The changes:

1. Replace `thread = QThread()` with `thread = QThread(self)`
2. Replace `thread.started.connect(lambda func: object.begin("argument"))` with `thread.started.connect(lambda: object.begin("argument"))`